# savechanges() saving one entity and not other

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactionscope, savechanges

A weird situation has struck me this code was running successfully two days back, but i dont know why its not running as before now :

```
public static void ChangeStatus(int sessionID, int? participantID, Guid? temporaryParticipantID, int statustypeID)
{
    using (EMSEntities entities = new EMSEntities())
    using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
    {
        try
        {
            SessionParticipant sessionParticipant = null;
            CurrentSessionSeatsStatu sessionCurrentStatus = null;
            if (participantID != null)
            {
                sessionParticipant = entities.SessionParticipants
                                             .Where(a => a.SessionID == sessionID && a.ParticipantID == participantID)
                                             .FirstOrDefault();
            }
            else if (temporaryParticipantID != null)
            {
                sessionParticipant = entities.SessionParticipants
                                             .Where(a => a.SessionID == sessionID && a.TemporaryParticipantID == temporaryParticipantID)
                                             .FirstOrDefault();
            }
            if (sessionParticipant != null)
            {
                sessionParticipant.StatusTypeID = statustypeID; // Status Changed here
            }
            **if (sessionParticipant.StatusTypeID == 2) // verified status
            {
                sessionCurrentStatus = entities.CurrentSessionSeatsStatus
                                               .Where(a => a.SessionID == sessionID)
                                               .FirstOrDefault();
                if (sessionCurrentStatus.SeatsLeft > 0)
                {
                    sessionCurrentStatus.SeatsLeft = sessionCurrentStatus.SeatsLeft - 1;
                }
            }**
            entities.SaveChanges();
            ts.Complete();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ts.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that changes(in StatusTypeID) for sessionParticipant are not saved in database but sessionCurrentStatus changes are !

no error thrown nothing !

Edit: I have discovered that the change in `sessionparticipant` is happening in all cases except when the status is changed to verified.
ie. when the other table viz. `sessioncurrentstatus` is updated in the if block.
That is whenever it goes in this `if block(bold in code)` the problem takes place.

Finally i found the problem and i think its because of the below code however it would be good if someone can explain the exact reason:

```
EMS.DAL.DALHelper.AttachAndSaveChanges(sessionParticipant, System.Data.EntityState.Modified); // the position of this code line can be found in the below code
```

below is the code which called the ChangesStatus method:

```
protected void ddlStatuses_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < gridViewEvents.VisibleRowCount; i++)
    {
        if (gridViewEvents.Selection.IsRowSelected(i))
        {
            EMS.DAL.SessionParticipant sessionParticipant = (EMS.DAL.SessionParticipant)gridViewEvents.GetRow(i);
            EMS.DAL.Session session = EMS.DAL.DALHelper.GetSessionById(sessionParticipant.SessionID);
            EMS.DAL.DALHelper.ChangeStatus(sessionParticipant.SessionID, sessionParticipant.ParticipantID, sessionParticipant.TemporaryParticipantID, Convert.ToInt32(ddlStatuses.SelectedItem.Value));
            if (ddlStatuses.SelectedItem.Value == "2" || ddlStatuses.SelectedItem.Value == "3") // if accepted or rejected
            {
                if (ddlStatuses.SelectedItem.Value == "2")  // verified/accepted
                {
                    EMS.DAL.DALHelper.SendMail("Congratulations! your participation for " + session.Name + " event has been confirmed.", "", sessionParticipant.Email, "");
// AT THIS POINT THE 'sessionParticipant' did not have the changed status which was set in the ChangeStatus method
                    sessionParticipant.IsNotified = true;
                    EMS.DAL.DALHelper.AttachAndSaveChanges(sessionParticipant, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);  // culprit as per me

                    List<EMS.DAL.SessionAttendanceList> attendanceList = EMS.DAL.DALHelper.GetSessionAttendanceList(session.ID);
                    attendanceList.ForEach(a =>
                    {
                        EMS.DAL.AttendanceListDetail attendanceListDetail = a.AttendanceListDetails.Where(p => p.ParticipantID == sessionParticipant.ParticipantID).FirstOrDefault();
                        if (attendanceListDetail == null)
                        {
                            attendanceListDetail.AttendanceListID = a.ID;
                            attendanceListDetail.ParticipantID = sessionParticipant.ParticipantID.Value;
                            attendanceListDetail.IsPresent = false;
                            EMS.DAL.DALHelper.AttachAndSaveChanges(attendanceListDetail, System.Data.EntityState.Added);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else if (ddlStatuses.SelectedItem.Value == "3") // denied/rejected
                {
                    EMS.DAL.DALHelper.SendMail("Your participation for " + session.Name + " event has been denied.", "", sessionParticipant.Email, "");
                    sessionParticipant.IsNotified = true;
                    EMS.DAL.DALHelper.AttachAndSaveChanges(sessionParticipant, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
                    List<EMS.DAL.SessionAttendanceList> attendanceList = EMS.DAL.DALHelper.GetSessionAttendanceList(session.ID);
                    attendanceList.ForEach(a =>
                    {
                        EMS.DAL.AttendanceListDetail attendanceListDetail = a.AttendanceListDetails.Where(p => p.ParticipantID == sessionParticipant.ParticipantID).FirstOrDefault();
                        if (attendanceListDetail != null)
                        {
                            EMS.DAL.DALHelper.AttachAndSaveChanges(attendanceListDetail, System.Data.EntityState.Deleted);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                List<EMS.DAL.SessionAttendanceList> attendanceList = EMS.DAL.DALHelper.GetSessionAttendanceList(session.ID);
                attendanceList.ForEach(a =>
                {
                    EMS.DAL.AttendanceListDetail attendanceListDetail = a.AttendanceListDetails.Where(p => p.ParticipantID == sessionParticipant.ParticipantID).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (attendanceListDetail != null)
                    {
                        EMS.DAL.DALHelper.DeleteAttendanceListDetail(attendanceListDetail);
                    }
                });
                attendanceList.ForEach(a =>
                {
                    EMS.DAL.DALHelper.DeleteSessionAttendanceList(a);
                });
            }
        }
    }
    gridViewEvents.DataBind();
    RefreshSeats();
}
```

Comment: A remark : you don't need to call ts.Dispose() since you are in a using block. Dispose will be automatically called when reaching the end of the using block.

Comment: any clue about my problem ?

Comment: No sorry. It effectively doesn't make sense. Check and recheck in the debugger that you are effectively passing in the update of your field. Check that you are checking the good database, and not some production/test database. Check your connection string too.

Comment: Another subtle point, transaction scope here adds no real value, a single save changes call is already transactional

Comment: @LukeMcGregor, even if multiple tables are in modified state ?

Comment: @Scorpi0, thanks pro trying hard

Comment: @tariq yeah even when multiple tables are involved, the operation save changes persists the whole local state at once it is essentially a unit of work

Comment: @Scorpi0, can you now spot the problem

Comment: Do you call the `ChangeStatus` method inside another `TransactionScope`?